# Codeception: Class "tests\_support\AcceptanceTester" does not exist

Tags: codeception

New to `PHP` and Codeception, but not to programming.  I've just set up Codeception in my web site's root folder.

During the install, I ran:

```
php vendor/bin/codecept bootstrap
```

and

```
php vendor/bin/codecept build
```

`My _support/AcceptanceTester.php` contains this:

```
class AcceptanceTester extends \Codeception\Actor
{
    use _generated\AcceptanceTesterActions;

    /**
     * Define custom actions here
     */
}
```

and `acceptance.suite.yaml` has this:

```
actor: AcceptanceTester
modules:
    
enabled:
    

- PhpBrowser:
        

url: http://localhost/shop
    

- \Helper\Acceptance
step_decorators: ~
```

What am I missing???

Comment: I think you have to make the class yourself

Comment: How do you run tests?